# What is the 60th element in the colex order

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out how to answer questions like, what is the $n$th element of the colex order on three element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. For example how would I determine the $60$th element in the colex order?

Comment: $\binom 83=56$, so it's the fourth three-element set in the colex order with $9$ in it.

Comment: What about the 50th element?

Comment: Would I have to say it is the 15th element in the colex order with 8 in it? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Then the other two elements form the fifteenth element in the colex order of two-element sets. Fortunately $\binom 62=15$.

Comment: So would the 50th be {6,6,8}?

Comment: Is that a **three-element** set?

Comment: Sorry, {5,6,8}.

Comment: Please see the edit. Feel free to write this in an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85286/discussion-between-fosho-and-lord-shark-the-unknown).